# Allow setting version per-example, not just per-topic

Tags: support, documentation

Pretty self-explanatory. Some examples will only work from a specific version that not everyone might have updated to yet.

Comment: MM? Wasn't that per-version thingy a slider?

Comment: @Braiam I have no idea how the versioning works yet :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add comments defining the version of specific examples (or parts of examples). See for example [this one I created recently](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/188/objects/2593/creating-an-iterable-object#t=201607211442097156648).

```
<!-- if version [gte 6] -->
...
<!-- end version if -->
```

Comment: I sure hope there's a way to somehow filter out the versions that don't interest you. I also expect that there's not because gosh.

Comment: Ok, now what the heck that syntax means?

Comment: Can you clarify where to put this syntax to make an entire example only apply above a particular version?

Comment: I just wrapped the entire contents in the comments, @Mark. There doesn't seem to be a way of marking the example itself.

Comment: Cool. Any idea if there's a way to mark an entire *topic* as only applying above a particular version, rather than just an example?

Comment: I haven't done it myself, but there's supposed to be a slider or something for topics.

Comment: I'm not overly fond of this solution, as the version box is not terribly obvious. I'd like it to be more obvous that the *entire example* is only relevant in Version X and onwards.