# How to version-tag documentation that applies from some version onwards

Tags: support, documentation

MySQL's JSON data type was only added in v5.7.8, which is fairly recent (5.8 isn't yet out). Consequently, somebody has [proposed adding the MySQL 5.7 version tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/46411?draftId=39879) to the topic about it.

This version tag will obviously become outdated as soon as a newer version comes out. As such, it seems unhelpful.

Really, we need a way to indicate that some documentation applies *before* some version, *from* some version, or within a *range* of versions, but since we don't yet have that, how should we tag these cases?

Comment: <!-- if version [gt 5.7.8] -->JSON data type<!-- end if version -->

Comment: @Braiam huh? Where am I supposed to type this? As the topic title? I can't find any documentation about specifying versions this way.

Comment: Stuff is all over the place so it doesn't surprise me: http://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-versions [Allow setting version per-example, not just per-topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328537) and I presume you know how to set them per topic.

Comment: @Braiam aha, just found http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#inline-versions which seems to be the official docs on this syntax. However, no indication on how to apply this to entire topics.

Comment: There should be a topic version in the editor.

Comment: @Braiam not for me - I just have a fixed set of versions that I can select or deselect, no free text field. Are we seeing a different UI from each other?

Comment: This is a real issue. For another example: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angularjs/295/hello-world#t=201608022205400825243 How should this distinguish between Angular 1 and 2?