# We don't need a C++11 documentation tag

Tags: support, status-completed, documentation, documentation-tags, tag-alias-request

[This is a thing that exists now](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2B%2B11). It probably shouldn't; the existing C++ documentation covers it just fine.

And while you're at it, go ahead and stop C++14, which is 2/5ths committed.

Here's a more complete list of tags:

- [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)
- [c++14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14)
- [c++1z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1z)
- [stl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stl)
- [stdbind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdbind)
- [std-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std-function)
- [variadic-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic-templates)

Comment: [A while back, Kevin Montrose said they have a way to alias tags for the purposes of documentation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328653/documentation-should-actively-reject-pledge-to-versioned-tags/329860#329860), but that the tool was restricted to team members. They've aliased [css3] to [css], but so far have been unwilling or unable to respond to any other requests from the community to do the same on other tags. I've raised *several* moderator flags on useless, version-specific Documentation (like windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10, etc.) that have been ignored.

Comment: @CodyGray I thought moderators had no access to Documentation at the moment. And the linked question says you should make a request on meta, like done there and here.

Comment: @uh oh somebody needs a pupper: That's why he specifically said "team members" and not "moderators".

Comment: @BoltClock How do you raise moderator flags on Documentation then? Edit: [nvm](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328506/we-need-to-be-able-to-flag-problematic-documentation-tags#comment369507_328523)

Comment: In case anybody don't know, we have [version markup](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329331#comment372240_329331).

Comment: @CodyGray AFAIK, they want you to submit several meta questions asking for this. So, I recommend Nicol to add all the C++ tags he wants aliased to the C++ tag documentation, like standard libraries, version tags, etc.

Comment: @CodyGray To be fair we did ask for css3 to be killed like 30 times

Comment: This is done now.

Comment: @shog9 I see that you synonymized/aliased the [visual-c++] tag as well. I'm not completely convinced that is appropriate. It makes sense to me to separate the compiler-specific stuff into separate tags. We still have, for example, documentation for the [gcc tag](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/gcc/topics). [visual-c++] would just be the equivalent for Microsoft's compiler. Do you think that these compiler-specific tags are not useful for Documentation purposes? (That's entirely possible; I still don't know what's being sought here.)

Comment: Let's see how GCC and [Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/visual-studio) pan out, @Cody. IME, [tag:visual-c++] is heavily misused in Q&A, but there may be a niche for it.

Comment: Fair enough. Visual Studio is *not* a compiler, but you're probably right that the distinction is lost on the majority of taggers. I'll work on my OCD (no I won't).

Answer (score -16):

### Edit

After some feedback, perhaps it might be useful to alias tags to topic examples, e.g. alias C++11 to VermillionAzure's "Modernizing C++" topic section. This would provide the same functionality without branching the existing tag.

### Original post

I'm one of the backers of this tag. I thought for a bit before backing it, for your very concerns. I finally decided to back it because:

- Documentation by example is what documentation is all about;
- Effective Modern C++ by Scott Meyers is an entire book of examples on how to use C++11;
- C++11 is a very active tag precisely because it's such a drastic overhaul of C++98/03;
- Examples of "how you did it before" and "how you do it now" are on topic for the tag;
- We have a simple [list](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/2742/the-iso-c-standard/16712/c11#t=201608051129211248708) to cover what's in C++11, but we don't have many **examples** of how this changes everyday usage.

There are scattershot examples in the main C++ tag that apply to C++11 (and later) but don't directly address the common usage of the C++11 tag: "how do I do it now?"

Examples:

- Transitioning from `auto_ptr` to `unique_ptr`,
- Using trailing return types and the `auto` keyword,
- Deprecated language features,
- `enable_if` (should be moved from C++) and linked to in the C++ tag, and
- Quite a bit more can be moved to C++11 and linked in C++.

I understand documentation is still in early days and we all have different ideas of what's good and what is not. Making C++11 the location for C++11-specific examples and then linking from C++ where appropriate makes too much sense to me not to do it.

Comment: I personally don't feel that C++11 deserves it's own documentation category tag simply because there exists version tags within the C++ page. However, if a C++11 page were to be allowed, should a C++14 page be allowed? C++17? I do agree that C++ is a very large language with very different features based on what feature you are using, but C++ has tried hard to keep backwards compatibility and keep C++ as *one language.*

If anything, I would support a "Modernizing to C++11" topic under the C++ tag. But even then, why C++11 and not C++14? For these reasons, I respectfully disagree.

Comment: LOTS of examples in the main C++ tag illustrate how to solve a problem in C++03 vs C++11 vs C++14 vs C++17.

Comment: links can be easily broken.

Comment: @Vermillion Hmm. You make a good point about a modernizing topic. I'll leave this here, despite the massive downvotes it's likely to receive, simply for the sake of continued discussion.

Comment: @DanielA.White not sure what you mean by that, but no link on docs will ever break (unless they unship the feature).

Comment: `C++Next` or `C++TheSequel` or `C+++`

Comment: Hmm. `C++++`? I wonder if it's a bad omen that the very name of the language invokes undefined behavior...